# Using custom author name in a node instead of author field

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a display name field I created for my users (available in account settings). I'd like to display the display name in the node if the person authored that node. I see I have an author field I can use... but that displays the login of the user, while I want to display their pretty display name that I setup instead. Is there a way to include this field instead of the author field?

In views it's easy to do, but I'm trying to use the field in a node.

Comment: did you try entity reference field ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module for it. You can choose which custom user field to use. This module only works for drupal 6 and drupal 7 https://www.drupal.org/project/realname

Comment: that worked easily - thank you. I just added the module and in the configuration I chose the display name field I already set up. saved the configuration and voila! the name appears that way on the node. nice.